# Programmatically adding several columns to Spark DataFrame

Tags: sql, json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using spark with scala.

I have a Dataframe with 3 columns: ID,Time,RawHexdata.
I have a user defined function which takes RawHexData and expands it into X more columns. It is important to state that for each row X is the same (the columns do not vary). However, before I receive the first data, I do not know what the columns are. But once I have the head, I can deduce it.

I would like a second Dataframe with said columns: Id,Time,RawHexData,NewCol1,...,NewCol3.

The "Easiest" method I can think of to do this is:
1. deserialize each row into json (every data tyoe is serializable here)
2. add my new columns, 
3. deserialize a new dataframe from the altered json,

However, that seems like a waste, as it involves 2 costly and redundant json serialization steps. I am looking for a cleaner pattern.

Using case-classes, seems like a bad idea, because I don't know the number of columns, or the column names in advance.

Comment: Could you provide more details? An example of data contained in `RawHexdata` maybe.

Comment: you can always apply `.withColumn()` function only after some conditions have been satisfied

Comment: Rawhexdata is a giant binary blob sent in by a bunch of embedded devices. I contains data which will be deserialized into other flat numeric data: doubles, ints, complex numbers and such. I would later like to enable an analyst to query this data with Sparksql. However, when the data is in a blob this is not possible, So I have written a UDF "parseblob" which takes a blob and returns a map/json object (i can change the return type to suit the soulution). I would like the contents of this map to be the columns in another table, where each row is related to the orginal raw data.

Comment: @niemand, withcolumn allows one cloumn at a time. Is there anyway I can use withcolumn without reparsing the entire blob for every column I add? (say I want to add 3 columns for example). If so, I could easily add a function that adds multiple columns by calling withcolumn repeadtely, However, Every synthax of withcolumn that I can think of requires reparsing raw data multiple times per row. I'm not very experienced with Scala, maybe there is some way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do to dynamically extend your `DataFrame` is to operate on the row RDD which you can obtain by calling `dataFrame.rdd`. Having a `Row` instance, you can access the `RawHexdata` column and parse the contained data. By adding the newly parsed columns to the resulting `Row`, you've almost solved your problem. The only thing necessary to convert a `RDD[Row]` back into a `DataFrame` is to generate the schema data for your new columns. You can do this by collecting a single `RawHexdata` value on your driver and then extracting the column types.

The following code illustrates this approach.

```scala
object App {

  case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test").setMaster("local[4]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._

    val input = sc.parallelize(Seq(Person("a", 1), Person("b", 2)))
    val dataFrame = input.df

    dataFrame.show()

    // create the extended rows RDD
    val rowRDD = dataFrame.rdd.map{
      row =>
        val blob = row(1).asInstanceOf[Int]
        val newColumns: Seq[Any] = Seq(blob, blob * 2, blob * 3)
        Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq.init ++ newColumns)
    }

    val schema = dataFrame.schema

    // we know that the new columns are all integers
    val newColumns = StructType{
      Seq(new StructField("1", IntegerType), new StructField("2", IntegerType), new StructField("3", IntegerType))
    }

    val newSchema = StructType(schema.init ++ newColumns)

    val newDataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, newSchema)

    newDataFrame.show()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, though  I don't know the type of each specific numerical value . I can add a "switch" and build the Seq function

Comment: Exactly @eshalev, assuming that all your `RawHexdata` contain the same columns, you can collect one `RawHexdata` object and calculate the data types for the resulting columns.

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT` is your friend solving it without going back to RDD.

```scala
case class Entry(Id: String, Time: Long)

val entries = Seq(
  Entry("x1", 100L),
  Entry("x2", 200L)
)

val newColumns = Seq("NC1", "NC2", "NC3")

val df = spark.createDataFrame(entries)
  .select(col("*") +: (newColumns.map(c => lit(null).as(c))): _*)

df.show(false)

+---+----+----+----+----+
|Id |Time|NC1 |NC2 |NC3 |
+---+----+----+----+----+
|x1 |100 |null|null|null|
|x2 |200 |null|null|null|
+---+----+----+----+----+
```